Footers for outdoor kitchen counters? Rocky Mountains
I am interested in building an 8x8 L-shaped outdoor kitchen in the foothills of the rockies (7800').  It will also have 3 - 4x4 uprights to support a roof (There will be a 4th post as well)  The soil is very rocky with a high clay content.  Very difficult to dig even a small hole.  It doesn't get extremely cold here but there are about 8 to 9 months where it will go well below freezing and then be in the 70's the next day.  I'm planning on concrete countertops.  The boxes themselves will be cedar 4x4 construction.  Some drawers but mostly firewood space, so they will be heavy.  I am trying to determine what kind of footings I need to prevent movement.
Deep footings in this climate will be a pain.  I see a lot of wood sheds with a couple of horizontal 6x6's for the base that don't appear to have sunk over the years, but I am also aware that any sinking at all could cause the counter to crack.  I'm not opposed to abandoning the L-shape and just making two slabs if that's significant easier.
What I am looking for is the right way to do it, and possibly a second best option if I eliminate the L-shaped counter top.
**** Update ****
Based on the comments, it sounds like I will have to worry about some shifting with shallow footers, but not necessarily sinking.  With this I am expanding my question based on the comments.
Assuming the goal was still and 8x8 L-shaped counter with a sloped roof and a 4th upright column to bear the weight of the roof.  Also I'm planning for some type of natural pavers for the floor:
I'm thinking a 10'x10' square created from pressure treated, lapped 6"x6"s.  In addition I would notch in 2"x4"'s on 12" centers on the bottom of the square.  I would need to dig out an area to bury the square so that the top was roughly flush.  I would frame the counters off of the 6"x6"s and for the 4th post I'd provide additional support at the base and find a way to make anything visible decorative.  The 2"x4" would aide in reduction of flex at the corners and allow for a packed gravel substrate without interfering with base layers of mortar for the natural pavers.
What are thoughts on this method?

You could consider screw piles with a grade beam to avoid having to dig too much.

Shads supported on the surface don't tend to sink, unless the supports are too small and they are in a swamp. But the whole shed moves with the ground freezing.  If you are not picky about the counters being/staying level, build their support structure so it will move as a whole, keeping them from breaking, and the need for footings goes away.

Am I thinking about this wrong or why can't this just be an independent structure?    Flatten ground below it or build a deck but make cabinets/L above it independent.   That way if there is movement you structure could be moved or altered.
